# How to determine whether the Timer task has completed

Tags: java, android, timer, timertask

I have this following code :

```
Timer timer = new Timer();      
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
};

timer.schedule(task, 10000);//execute after 10 seconds
```

Can we determine whether the task is already executed by the timer or is still due?

Answer (score 6):

Add a simple variable like..

```
  boolean isTaskCompleted = false;
  Timer timer = new Timer();      
  TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

     @Override
     public void run() {
        // do stuff
        isTaskCompleted = true;
     }
  };

  timer.schedule(task, 10000);//execute after 10 seconds
```

Comment: This is a good idea! But When I call the same task from multiple times for multiple purposes. However, I have different timer variables to cancel different tasks.  How can I find that the task corresponding to that perticular timer is running or not.

Answer (score 3):

Sure,

```
class CustomTask extends TimerTask {
    protected boolean isDone = false;
    public boolean isDone() {return isDone; }

    @Override
        public void run() {}
} 

CustomTask task = new CustomTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       isDone=true;
    }
 };
```

EDIT:
If you are not happy with extending the class, you could use the method scheduledExecutionTime(), this returns 0 if the task have not been run.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html

Comment: i know about this workaround.. But problem here is that isDone() cannot be called explicitly unless you extend TimerTask. But i wanted to know if there is any api from TimerTask for this..

Comment: thanks.. but android doc for scheduledExecutionTime() says this : Tasks which have not yet run return an undefined value.         http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html#scheduledExecutionTime()

Comment: java doesn't have an "undefined" type, and the method declaration shows it will return a long, hence it cant be null. This undefined value is 0. Try it :)